# Customizing 1 theme for multiple blogs in a multisite setup

Tags: themes, multisite, customization

I just converted a site to a multisite setup using WordPress 3.0.4.  One thing I found in a hurry is that if I wanted to edit a theme's code, the changes would be reflected on all the subsites that use the same theme.  Is there a to customize the code so that only a certain subsite receives the changes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just css customizations, use this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/safecss/

It's what wp.com uses for their css upgrade.

If you have to edit the php, make a copy of the theme with a new name on the theme folder and in style.css.

Comment: I should have thought of copying the theme.  Thank you